# How to disable HTML hierarchy tracking at bottom of screen in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How do I get rid of this?

[image]

The reason I want to get rid of it is that every so often, I will move my mouse down toward the bottom of the screen, and when I mouseover this area, the mouse jumps all the way to the top-left of my screen. It's real annoying. I actually have to make my mouse go around this "feature" which I never use anyways, and probably just adds to the overhead VS introduces. So, any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That area is called the Quick Tab Selector. This looks to be baked in with VS2008 and it's sibling IDEs (Expression, FrontPage).

But Expression Web looks like it is the only IDE that allows you to turn it off:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295520(v=Expression.30).aspx

After doing some personal poking around for longer than I probably should have on VS2008 and VS2010, I didn't see anything in VSSettings, the registry, project properties, SLN properties, or any of the other usual suspects for this kind of thing.